# Изменить заголовок в ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbar

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите как можно изменить заголовок в actionBar
Побывал так

```
            ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
            actionbar.setTitle(query);
```

Но actionbar = null
Других способов пока не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какой api ты используешь.

- android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

  `ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();`
- android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

  `ActionBar ab = getActionBar();`
- android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity

  `ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();`

Если интересен детальный разбор то - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867076/getactionbar-returns-null

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что вы используете Android Support Library, поэтому код должен быть таким.

```
ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
actionbar.setTitle(query);
```